# Add relative Image URL to hash name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, gulp

In my ReactJS Application I have image structure created for each domain and in Webpack Configuration using file loader, I have images converted to hash name and copied at some asset folder after build process.

And I need to have a reference to this images in one of the data file which is a json file format and contains a imageurl property which would consist of the Image name. But the problem is after deploying it on some stagging server where there would be just a build output folder present, the relative path images are no more copied to the Output directory(due to build size constraint) so image url property results in Image not found error.

Is there any way to add reference to these images apart from adding some build script to map image maps to hash image name?

```
 App
  |
 General Resource
  |     |
  |  SomeInfo -Json 
  |
 ImageResources
  |
  A
  |-- A.png
  |-- B.jpeg


On build - Output is

App
  |
 Assets
  |- 123.png (random hash code)
  |- 345.jpeg
```

So I have to add a reference to A.png in my SomeInfo.jso file but as per build output ~A/A.png image should converts to Assets/123.png.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the images to have the hash added to their filename? If not, you should set up your emit file to not include the hash when processing the image. I am guessing your images are being processed by your [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#name). Take a look at your webpack config and see where you are setting a `[hash]` to be set on those files. When you remove that hash, you will have a deterministic filename to reference.

Comment: Yes, I need to have hash file name only as per the project requirement.